# Removing Specific value (or item) from Key in Scripting Dictionary

Tags: vba

I am comparing two VBA scripting dictionaries. Particularly, I want to know if the keys that have the same name (in this example, "Dogs") also have the same values/items assigned to them. If there is a mismatch (one key has more items than the other), I want to know where the difference comes from.

In this example, I have two identically named keys in two scripting dictionaries, but one has 3 values and the other has 4.

I want to see which values ("Mixed" and "Cat") are missing from the key in the first dictionary. I then want to make a string of the values that are missing.

```
Set Dictionary1 = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
Set Dictionary2 = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

Dictionary1.Add "Dogs", Array("Beagle", "Setter", "Chiuhuaha")
Dictionary2.Add "Dogs", Array("Beagle", "Setter", "Chiuhuaha", "Mixed", "Cat")
```

**Objective**:

```
MissingItems = Mixed &" "& Cat
MsgBox "The missing items in Dogs are" & MissingItems
```

Does anyone have an idea of how this could be achieved? I'd greatly appreciate it if you could suggest the code wording to use. I'm so stuck!

Comment: There is no quick way to do this in VBA.  Instead you will have to iterate one of the dictionaries, use the keys returned to get the equivalent item in the second dictionary and then compare the arrays item by item.  It will be simpler to process the arrays into more scripting.dictionaries using the values as keys.  Its a very straighforward (if somewhat tdious)  process which you should find easy to implement.

Comment: What about if dict1 key has values not present in matching dict2 key's value? How are you keeping track of which dict items are missing from? @freeflow's suggestion seems like a good one.

Comment: My question really is about when the two keys have the same name but different values. I simply have no idea how to select only those values that don't exist... I tried running two loops to detect duplicates but then don't know how to remove them one by one from key of dictionary 2... I am so lost and spent hours on this. Any help in the form of concrete code would be super appreciated!

Comment: Could someone help me please :-(?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    Dim dictionary1 As Object: Set dictionary1 = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Dim dictionary2 As Object: Set dictionary2 = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
 
    dictionary1.Add "Dogs", Array("Beagle", "Setter", "Chiuhuaha")
    dictionary2.Add "Dogs", Array("Beagle", "Setter", "Chiuhuaha", "Mixed", "Cat")
    
    Const myKey As String = "Dogs"
    
    'Exit if key is missing from any of the dictionaries
    If Not dictionary1.Exists(myKey) Then Exit Sub
    If Not dictionary2.Exists(myKey) Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim elements1 As Object: Set elements1 = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim missingElements As Object: Set missingElements = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    'Create another dictionary with the elements of the first array
    For Each v In dictionary1(myKey)
        elements1(v) = Empty 'This creates the key if missing and makes sure you don't have duplicates
    Next v
    
    'Check all missing elements from the second array
    For Each v In dictionary2(myKey)
        If Not elements1.Exists(v) Then
            missingElements(v) = Empty
        End If
    Next v
    
    If missingElements.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No items missing in " & myKey, vbInformation, "Result"
    Else
        MsgBox "The missing items in " & myKey & " are: " & Join(missingElements.Keys, " ")
    End If
   
End Sub
```

Comment: Works like a charm - incredible, and so simple! You saved my Sunday Cristian :-) Unbelievably grateful!!!

Comment: @ClaRosie Glad it helped. If you add a reference to 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime' ([printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fm5tq.png)) then you can ditch the late-binding and declare your dictionaries with ```Dim dictionary1 As Dictionary: Set dictionary1 = New Dictionary```. This will make the dictionaries faster and give you Intellisense. Also, the whole code can be rewritten with using just VBA.Collection objects instead of dictionaries but it would be a bit more complicated to write.